# Mac OS: Bash GetOpts Sometimes Ignored

Tags: bash, macos, getopts

I wrote a small bash script in my bash_profile. I want to use `getopts` to parse options.

```
deployMenu() {
  noInstallDependencies='false'
  build='true'
  echo "Args: $@"

  while getopts 'db' flag; do
    echo "flag ${flag}"
    case "${flag}" in
      d) noInstallDependencies='true' ;;
      b) build='false' ;;
      #*) echo "Unexpected option ${flag}" ;;
      #\?) echo "Unexpected option ${flag}" ;;
    esac
  done

  echo "noInstallDependencies $noInstallDependencies"
  echo "build $build"
```

If I run the command multiple times, the argument is ignored. I have to run diff. flags in order to get it recognized.

```
User:project User$ deployMenu -b
Args: -b
noInstallDependencies false
build true

User:project User$ deployMenu -b
Args: -b
noInstallDependencies false
build true

User:project User$ deployMenu --b -b
Args: --b -b
flag b
noInstallDependencies false
build false

User:project User$ deployMenu --b -b
Args: --b -b
noInstallDependencies false
build true
```

As you can see the flag is only recognized after altering the params from `-b` to `--<something> -b`. I first thought the first param is ignored but running twice `--b -b` also fails. Is there any cache or anything to reset first? To get it working by first using `-b` and then switching to `--b -b` is reproducible.

Comment: `getopts` doesn't support long options like `--b`.

Comment: Thx, I know the problem is that it is ignoring -b

Comment: I can also use only -b and it is still ignored. This was just an example that it only works when changing args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are calling a shell function repeatedly in the same shell instance, the value of `$OPTIND` isn't being reset between calls to `deployMenu`. This affects which option `getopts` sees as "next" each time it is called. Try your same experiment with `deployMenu ...; echo $OPTIND`. The solution is probably just to explicitly set `OPTIND=1` if you plan on calling `deployMenu` multiple times.

```
deployMenu() {
  noInstallDependencies='false'
  build='true'
  echo "Args: $@"
  OPTIND=1

  while getopts 'db' flag; do
   ...
}
```